How can I import the different "properties" that my files have in SharePoint?
I am importing various folders with different Excel files in them with Power Query.
I am using the following command:
SharePoint.Contents(url as text, optional options as nullable record) as table
as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharepoint-contents
This command doesn't import all the properties each file has, that are like "tags", and help differentiate the different types of documents and also to know if one file is the latest version or it is archived.
How can I export all this information which is really useful for me?
Thank you.
I have tried the following:
SharePoint.Contents(url as text, optional options as nullable record) as table
as described in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/sharepoint-contents
